# Function return on an int returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a simple function which sums each individual number in a string of numbers until it becomes a single unit, e.g. "55555" -> 5+5+5+5+5 = 25 -> 2+5 = 7 but my function always returns undefined, the code works and I can console.log the correct answer but the actual function always returns undefined

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  checkDigit = 0
  for (i = 0; i < membershipId.length; i++) {
    checkDigit += parseInt(membershipId.substring(i, i + 1));
  }
  if (checkDigit.toString().length > 1) {
    createCheckDigit(checkDigit.toString())
  } else {
    return checkDigit;
  }

}
```

if I `console.log(checkDigit)` in the else statement for a function call `createCheckDigit("55555")` it displays 7 which is correct, but the function itself always returns undefined

Comment: You don't return anything if the condition passes.

Comment: if () no return, else { returns }

Comment: The recursive call is returning, the recursing call is not.

Comment: @Teemu but isn't that correct? Because I want the function to keep calling itself until the last condition is not satisfied

Comment: --> `checkDigit = 0` is also scary

Comment: Tip: use this: `return membershipId % 9 || 9` instead of all that other stuff.

Comment: instead of using substring, why not just use `membershipId[i]`

Comment: @MikeSamuel Ah okay I understand this now, thanks guys!

Comment: @Isomorphism420 Nope, beacuse the execution is eventually returned next to the line the recursion started. At that point or after it there's no return statement for the function you originally have called.

Answer (score 1):

When creating recursive functions, you need to `return` the result of the recursive function call.

```
return createCheckDigit(checkDigit.toString());
```

Also, just a note, when using `parseInt` it's suggested to pass `10` as a 2nd parameter to make sure it returns what you expect.

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  let checkDigit = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < membershipId.length; i++) {
    checkDigit += parseInt(membershipId.substring(i, i + 1), 10);
  }
  if (checkDigit.toString().length > 1) {
    return createCheckDigit(checkDigit.toString())
  } else {
    return checkDigit;
  }
}

console.log(createCheckDigit('55555'));
```

I've also used `let` to declare your variables `checkDigit` and `i` inside the function scope only and not leaked into the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return` sentence on the recursive call, otherwise the result of the recursive call will be lost:

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId)
{
    let checkDigit = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < membershipId.length; i++)
    {
        checkDigit += parseInt(membershipId.substring(i, i + 1));
    }

    if (checkDigit.toString().length > 1)
    {
        return createCheckDigit(checkDigit.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        return checkDigit;
    }
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, I'm more comfortable to always put the base condition of the recursive call at the beginning. Also, using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can do something like next:

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId)
{
    if (!parseInt(membershipId) || membershipId.length <= 1)
        return isNaN(+membershipId) ? 0 : +membershipId;

    return createCheckDigit(
        membershipId.split("").reduce((acc, n) => ((+acc) + (+n)).toString())
    );
}

console.log("Result for '55555':", createCheckDigit("55555"));
console.log("Result for null:", createCheckDigit(null));
console.log("Result for undefined:", createCheckDigit(undefined));
console.log("Result for '1':", createCheckDigit("1"));
console.log("Result for 'foo':", createCheckDigit("foo"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note the usage of [Unary Plus Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to coerces digits from string to numbers, from **MDN**:

> **unary plus** is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and do a recursive function like this:

```js
const sumDigit = x => `${x}`.length > 1
  ? sumDigit([...`${x}`].reduce((sum, x) => sum + (+x), 0))
  : +x;

console.log(sumDigit('55555')); // 7
console.log(sumDigit('5555')); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateNm(numbers) {
  let num = numbers.split("");
  let newNum = num.reduce((acc, curr) => parseInt(acc) + parseInt(curr));
  if (newNum.toString().length > 1) {
    return calculateNm(newNum.toString());
  } else {
    return newNum;
  }
}
calculateNm("55555");
```